# Ray tracing parallelizing computations on java swing using executor service

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, raytracing

I saw a lot of threads here talking only about sudo algorithms on how to parallalize ray tracing and i'm having a difficult time implementing it.

My current approach is as follows

```
ExecutorService fixedPool=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(/*don't know whats the best value for my system without crashing it*/);

private static final class DrawCall
{
 private final int x,y;
 private java.awt.Color pixelColor;

 private DrawCall(int x,int y,Color color)
 {
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
  this.color=color;
 }

 private void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
 {
  g2d.setColor(color);
  g2d.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
 }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
 ArrayList<Future<DrawCall>> calls=new ArrayList();//An Future for every pixel

 for(int x=0;x<width;x++)
 {
  for(int y=0;y<height;y++)
  {
   Future<DrawCall> call=fixedPool.submit(
                   ()->
                   {
                     //My ray tracing per pixel submitted as an lambda task to the executor service

                    if(intersection with scene){return new DrawCall(x,y,/*pixel color at that point*/);}
                    else{return null;//no op}
                   }
                  );

   calls.add(call);
  }
 }
  
 while(!calls.isEmpty())
 {
  calls.removeIf(callBack->
  {
   if(callBack.isDone())
   {
    DrawCall call=callBack.get();
    if(call!=null){call.draw((Graphics2D)g);}
   }  
   return callBack.isDone();
  });
 }
}
```

This dosen't improve the performance at all

I also tried rendering each pixel(rendered in the executor service) to an buffered image[synchronized on it] and then called the JPanel's repaint()[using SwingUtilities.invokeLater()] to paint the image on the screen with every pixel completed but the performance deteriorated even more.

For my assignment i am allowed to only use java swing so what is the best way to push pixels ASAP onto the screen parallelly?

Comment: Look at ImageRaster and how to effectively write to Swing images

Comment: @Polygnome  i did use the [WritableRaster](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) attached to the buffered image but all it's methods are not thread safe so i had to synchronize on it and when there are 1000+ threads trying to aquire an single raster performance suffers. Also calling repaint thousand or more times to repaint the bufferedimage on the JPanel with every pixel as i have discovered is an terrible idea :(